# How to get nested array from `sql/mysql` under a common column using `groupby` without using foreach to structure the data?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, group-by, eloquent

Lets say the table `tracker` contains this `columns(id,section,user_id,message)` and other one is `user` table which contains user data  and `user_id` is the foreign key in the table `tracker` so I am using `join` to get the name from `user` table and I am using `laravel`.

The response is like this:-

```
{'id'=1,'name'='pavan','section'='marketing','message'='something'}
```

The required structure is a nested array under `user_id` like this:-

```
{
//user_id 1:
  [name,section,message],
 2:
  [name,section,message]
}
```

How do I get this using `MySQL` query?

//user model

```
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
 use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

 class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
 {
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 }

 /**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function down()
 {
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
 }
 }
```

//tracker model

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('trackers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->enum('section',['Marketing','Sales','Customer','Trainer','Operations']);
        $table->string('subject')->nullable();
        $table->longText('content');
        $table->enum('status',['processing','resolved']);
        $table->date('date');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

    });
}
```

//get data method in tracker model

```
public function getdata(){
        return \DB::table('trackers')
        ->join('users','users.id','=','trackers.user_id')
        ->select('trackers.user_id','users.name',
          'trackers.created_at','trackers.id','date',
          'trackers.status','trackers.section','trackers.content')
          ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
        }
```

//query

```
 $dat=new Tracker;
  $data=$dat->getdata()->where('date',Carbon::today()->
  toDateString())->where('status','processing');
```

Comment: can you post the model or a query?

Comment: can this help to solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $dat=new Tracker;
  $data=$dat->getdata()->where('date',Carbon::today()->
  toDateString())->where('status','processing')->get();
```

`get()` will return the collection after getting the collection you can use

You can data like this with

```
$dat->groupBy('user_id');
```

This will return the data as you expected.

You can get more information about `collection->groupby()`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby

Comment: Thanks for your help